# Angular2 Reactive forms, FormControl default value in pristine status

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have created a form which allows the user to add additional text-inputs by clicking a button. The `FormControl`s behind these inputs are stored in a `FormArray` inside of a `FormGroup`.

I want to provide a default value for these inputs, that is going to be submitted if they are pristine. If the user changes the value of the input, which changes it to dirty, I do not want the default value to be submitted or displayed.

I currently am displaying the inputs like this, as the placeholder attribute does exactly what I want, displaying the default name, only if the input has not been changed.

```
<div
    formArrayName="names" 
    *ngFor="let server of names.controls; let i = index; trackBy:trackByFn">
        <span>{{ i + 1 }}</span>
        <input 
        type="text" 
        formControlName="{{i}}"
        placeholder="{{defaultName}}">

</div>
```

To validate the names I have created the following validation function:

```
export function validateServerName(form: FormGroup): ValidationErrors | null {
    const names: string[] = form.value[CREATE_FORM_KEY_NAMES];

    for (const name of names) {
        if (name.trim() === '') {
            return {
                invalidName: true
            };
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Here I am having trouble figuring out if the element is dirty or pristine, as `form.value[key]` only returns a string array, not an array of the FormControls.

I am looking for either an easier way to do what I am trying to achieve, or a way to validate the form properly.

Comment: you can use `form.get('controlname')`

Comment: Did you used formBuilder?

Comment: No @RIYAJKHAN, building on older code which was created when form builder did not exist yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can check the control status using

if touched is true then its dirty

```
this.form.get('controlname').touched
```

and for pristine you can check like

```
this.form.get('controlname').pristine
```

**UPDATE**

for form array it will be something like

```
  let val = this.user.get('<FormArray>') as FormArray;
  console.log(val.at(index));
```

you can now use `pristine` and `touched` on this variable

Comment: I need to access a control inside a `FormArray`, your answer helped to get me to the solution, but you might want to update it so the context is correct when I am accepting your answer.